# Get access gender details when gender is private in account

Tags: android, google-signin

I am able to get genders detail using api when they are as public in my account  but when gender details are private or only my circle then it always returns null.

Please tell me if is there any way to access gender details when they are private like using Scope because I didn't find any Scope for gender.

Comment: Just an idea, If it returns then you can prompt the User to select a Gender by showin an AlertDialog... :)

Comment: Thanks for replying...that was good idea but I am trying to get details because users providing fake details.